# Does LoadString allocate memory for the string it writes to?

Tags: c++, resources, stringreader, resourcestring

I am new in c++ and need some help.
I created a resource-only dll that contains strings, i need to use this dll in a different project to read the stored strings.

I wrote the following functions to read the read the strings:

```
LPTSTR GetResourceStr(HMODULE resContainer,int resourceID)
{
    //The stings that are stored in the dll are:
    //
    //ID            |Value|Caption
    //__________________________________________
    //IDS_STRING101 |101  |stringggg
    //IDS_STRING102 |102  |string 102
    //IDS_STRING103 |103  |string 103

    LPTSTR strBuffer = NULL;//is a (non-const) TCHAR string
    if(0!=resContainer){
      int copied=LoadString(resContainer,resourceID ,(LPTSTR)&strBuffer,0); 
    }
    return strBuffer;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HMODULE resContainer=LoadLibraryEx(L"ResourceDll.dll",NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);

    LPTSTR msg = GetResourceStr(resContainer,101);
    std::wcout<<msg<<std::endl;
    //Expected output: stringggg
    //The output that i get: stringgggstring 102 string 103
    int i = 0;
    std::cin>>i;
    return 0;
}
```

What should i change in my code to get the **expected output - stringggg**?
Why is it happening?
**Did LoadString allocate memory for the string it read from resources, or i just got pointer to the place in memory the string is already stored?**
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You need an LPTSTR[] so it can copy the string into your buffer.  Last argument must be the size of that array, 0 is never correct.  Returning that array will be a dangling pointer bug.  Consider returning an std::wstring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LoadString documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647486(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> nBufferMax [in]
>
> Type: int
>
> The size of the buffer, in characters. The string is truncated and null-terminated if it is longer than the number of characters specified. If this parameter is 0, then lpBuffer receives a read-only pointer to the resource itself.

So to answer your question directly, you just get a pointer to the memory where the resource is stored.

But the string resource is not null-terminated (for more info, see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040130-00/?p=40813)), so that's why you get that output. The return value of LoadString tells you the length of the individual string resource. If you need the string to be null-terminated, you have to copy the string to a separate buffer, like this:

```
WCHAR* pszString;
int iLength = ::LoadString(
    resContainer,
    resourceID,
    reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&pszString),
    0
    );

WCHAR* pszString2 = new WCHAR[iLength + 1];
::StringCchCopyN(pszString2, iLength + 1, pszString, iLength);
```

Alternatively, you can just call LoadString with a pointer to a buffer (instead of a pointer to a pointer) as the 3rd parameter, and the length of the buffer as the 4th parameter, which will copy the string resource to the buffer and null-terminate it. The disadvantage is that the string will be truncated if you don't pass a big enough length, and there's no way to query the resource's length beforehand.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped me to understand my mistake!!